# Difficulty with Arithmetic with Time in R

Tags: r, math, time

I'm new in R.
I have a table in .csv format with 12K rows like below:

```
St.    date     Rgtime   RadTime    Rain    dBZ
3613006 20130113    0:06:00  0:06:00    2    -10.625
3613006 20130113    0:16:00  0:16:00    7    -11.75
3613006 20130113    0:26:00  0:26:00    1    -10.5625
3613006 20130113    0:36:00  0:36:00    9    -11.28125
3613006 20130113    0:46:00  0:46:00    3    -10.34375
3613006 20130113    0:56:00  0:56:00    8    -11.6875
3613006 20130113    1:06:00  1:06:00    9    -16
3613006 20130113    1:16:00  1:16:00    6    -25.3125
3613006 20130113    1:26:00  1:26:00    1    -16.3125
3613006 20130113    1:36:00  1:36:00    0    -20.71875
```

I would like to add 2 columns:

1- $RgTime - 10 minutes  AS RadTimeNew

2- relevant dBZ to RadTimeNew  AS dBZ.New

Expected result:

```
St.     date       Rgtime   Rain    RadTime dBZ     RadTimeNew dBZ.New
3613006 20130113    0:06:00     2   0:06:00 -10.625      NA         NA
3613006 20130113    0:16:00     7   0:16:00 -11.75      0:06:00 -10.625
3613006 20130113    0:26:00     1   0:26:00 -10.5625    0:16:00 -11.75
3613006 20130113    0:36:00     9   0:36:00 -11.28125   0:26:00 -10.5625
3613006 20130113    0:46:00     3   0:46:00 -10.34375   0:36:00 -11.28125
3613006 20130113    0:56:00     8   0:56:00 -11.6875    0:46:00 -10.34375
3613006 20130113    1:06:00     9   1:06:00 -16         0:56:00 -11.6875
3613006 20130113    1:16:00     6   1:16:00 -25.3125    1:06:00 -16
3613006 20130113    1:26:00     1   1:26:00 -16.3125    1:16:00 -25.3125
3613006 20130113    1:36:00     0   1:36:00 -20.71875   1:26:00 -16.3125
```

I have tried to use `lag()`, but my data time is not continues and there are some error. So I am looking for a new script to deal with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(RadTimeNew = lag(RadTime), dBZ.New = lag(dBZ))` from the `dplyr` package. But take care that `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is set reading the data

Comment: Or use `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, c('RadTimeNew', 'dBZ.New') :=shift(.SD), .SDcols=c(4,6)][]`

Comment: @RStudent The code is not working!!!!

Comment: @Ali Seif Did you load the 'dplyr' package, otherwise it uses the basic version of 'lag'

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code :

```
  df <- within(All.data, {
  posb <- as.POSIXlt(Rgdate,format="%Y/%m/%d %T")
  Day <- posb$mday
  Month <- posb$mon
  Year <-posb$year
  hours <- posb$hour
  mins <- posb$min
  Seconds <-posb$sec
  Time <- format(posb, "%T")
  Date <- format(posb, "%x") 
  posb <- NULL  # cleanup
} )
```

This code will convert string to date and time and add new column in the end. Just you need to -10 miniutes from the minute column.

You can get more information about POSIXlt by `?POSIXlt`